# NSMutable Array crashed when being accessed at other method

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays, xcode, nsmutablearray

```
-(void)Aray
{
    NSMutableArray *ColorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    if(Counter < NewColor)
    {
        [ColorArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:ColorTemp]];

        Counter += 1;
    }
}

-(IBAction)Go:(id)sender
{
    NSMutableArray *ColorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    Color = [[ColorArray objectAtIndex:Index] intValue];

    if(Color == 2)
    {

        ColorLabel.text = @"The Color is Black";
        Screen.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BlackTile.png"];
    }
    else
    {
        Screen.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Tunnel.png"];
        ColorLabel.text = @"The Color is Green";
    }
    Index += 1;
}

-(IBAction)Black:(id)sender
{
    ColorTemp = 2;
    NewColor += 1;
    [self Array];
}

-(IBAction)Green:(id)sender
{
    ColorTemp = 1;
    NewColor += 1;
   [self Array];   
}
```

Comment: Which point does it crash etc etc etc

Comment: 2014-10-02 01:09:49.694 Testing[49737:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `ColorArray` needs to be an instance variable (or `@property`) of the class so that it persists *outside* of the method calls.

This code will **always** crash, regardless of the value of `Index`:

```
NSMutableArray *ColorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

Color = [[ColorArray objectAtIndex:Index] intValue];
```

`Color` appears to already be an instance variable (or `@property`), so this concept should not be alien to you.

Side note: variables conventionally start with lower case and use camal-case naming.

Comment: Well thanks for your guidance. Honestly I'm a newbie and just started learning programming about 3 weeks ago. So my basics are still messy.

Comment: I did some research and still confused how to make the array as an instance variable. please help.. many thanks